# How to add a list-unsubscribe header in amazon SES send_email function in python?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-ses, email-headers

This is my python code for amazon SES:

```
import mimetypes
from email import encoders
from email.utils import COMMASPACE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from boto.ses import SESConnection
class SESMessage(object):
    """
    Usage:

    msg = SESMessage('from@example.com', 'to@example.com', 'The subject')
    msg.text = 'Text body'
    msg.html = 'HTML body'
    msg.send()

    """

    def __init__(self, source, to_addresses, subject, **kw):
        self.ses = connection

        self._source = source
        self._to_addresses = to_addresses
        self._cc_addresses = None
        self._bcc_addresses = None

        self.subject = subject
        self.text = None
        self.html = None
        self.attachments = []

    def send(self):
        if not self.ses:
            raise Exception, 'No connection found'

        if (self.text and not self.html and not self.attachments) or \
           (self.html and not self.text and not self.attachments):
            return self.ses.send_email(self._source, self.subject,
                                       self.text or self.html,
                                       self._to_addresses, self._cc_addresses,
                                       self._bcc_addresses,
                                       format='text' if self.text else 'html')
        else:
            message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

            message['Subject'] = self.subject
            message['From'] = self._source
            if isinstance(self._to_addresses, (list, tuple)):
                message['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(self._to_addresses)
            else:
                message['To'] = self._to_addresses

            message.attach(MIMEText(self.text, 'plain'))
            message.attach(MIMEText(self.html, 'html'))
```

According to [amazon ses boto library](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ses_tut.html), i can send html or text or with attachment emails through **MIME** header, but how can i mention headers for normal text or html mails?. I need to attachment list-unsubscribe link from where user can unsubscribed.

If i send normal mail then if part run there i am not able to add header like message['list-unsubscribe'] = "http://www.xyaz.com"

Comment: Have you tried just doing "message['list-unsubscribe'] = ..." with the MIMEMultipart message object you are creating?

Comment: Never mind, I see you are asking about non-MIME messages.  Sorry.

Comment: I think you could use ``send-email-raw`` and construct the entire message yourself, including the additional headers you want to include.

Comment: @garnaat: this is what i thought about this, according to boto library we can send message using **send_raw_email(raw_message, source=None, destinations=None)**, should i append all header in body?. I am using html body.

Comment: If you use ``send_email_raw`` you have to compose the complete email message, headers and body, with ``To``, ``From``, etc.

Comment: @garnaat: i'll try and get back to u output

Comment: @garnaat: Using this request.headers = { 'X-List-Unsubscribe':'<http://www.wakkadroid.com/email>'} with function send_email is working but i didn't see header in gmail headers. If i am trying to use send_raw_email then it sends only html text, please help

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, but I faced the same issue for sometime and was not able to get the answer. I found the correctly working code by analyzing the original mail.

There were two important things that I was missing.

1. Reply-To
2. add_header method

The documentation shows the working code:

[AWS SES documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html)

You just have to add `Reply-To` argument and `List-Unsubscribe` header.

This is the working code.

```
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


def send_r_email():
    region_name = 'us-west-2'
    SENDER = "Google <no-reply@google.com>"
    RECIPIENT = "your-email@google.com"
    CONFIGURATION_SET = "your configuration set"
    SUBJECT = "Customer new subject contact info"
    BODY_TEXT = "Hello,\r\nPlease see the attached file for a list of customers to contact."
    BODY_HTML = """\
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
    """
    CHARSET = "utf-8"
    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=region_name)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = SENDER
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
    msg['Reply-To'] = "Google <abc@google.com>"
    msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
    htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)
    msg_body.attach(textpart)
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)
    msg.attach(msg_body)
    msg.add_header('List-Unsubscribe', '<http://somelink.com>')
    try:
        #Provide the contents of the email.
        response = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=SENDER,
            Destinations=[
                RECIPIENT
            ],
            RawMessage={
                'Data':msg.as_string(),
            },
            ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:")
        print(response['MessageId'])


send_r_email()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to fetch the 'List-Unsubscribe' header from .msg files ?

Answer (score -3):

$mail->AddReplyTo('mail@exmaple.com', 'Reply to name');
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: mailto:mail@example.com, http://example.com/unsubscribe/");